# Java noSuchMethodError: sun.security.pkcs/pkcs7

Tags: java, android

when I try to sign my apk for publish i get this error

[image]

i have checked, my application uses the jdk1.8.0_101, and my environmental variables Java_Home reference that specific folder too. I have also tried to update my Java but to no avail.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is irrelevant except to an IDE. What does `jarsigner -version` or `javac -version` print?

Comment: the jarsigner is in the same file as the jdkjdk1.8.0_101. But javac -version prints "javac 1.8.0_91".  Do you think that's the issue? how can I change it ?

Comment: my java version is "1.8.0_111" but i guess thats the jre because i don;t have that version in jdk

Comment: Do you have a CLASSPATH environment variable set? And if so does it contain any references to the JRE or JDK? If so, remove them, start a new command window, and try again.

Comment: no i dont have a CLASSPATH environment variable set, should i set it to to my jdk1.8.0_101?

Comment: No you shouldn't. Did you read what I wrote about it? This is really rather strange. I would be inclined to reinstall the JDK.

Comment: do you think changing the javac path would help?

Comment: No, why would it?